# How to slide a div and show a different content each time a toogle-slide is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, switch-statement, toggle

I am trying to switch between divs each time the toogle-slide button is clicked. Also the other buton should hide/show each time switch button is clicked.

html code:

```
<div id="divParticipants">
click 'on' to hide the button and show the second content 
</div>
<div id="divPackage" style='display:none'>
click 'off' to hide the button and hide first content 
</div>

<button type="button" id='add-new'>
another button 
</button>
```

javascript code:

```
$(function () {
        $('#package-toogle').change(function () {
            $('#divParticipants').hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 400, function () {
               $('#add-new').hide(); 
            });

            $('#divPackage').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 400, function () {
                $('#add-new').show();
            });
        })
    });
```

I spent half an hour trying to make it work but couldn't make it work. I would appreciate if you can show how to do it. Here is jsfiddle link.

https://jsfiddle.net/p9qarjg0/36/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using toggle instead.

```
      $(function () {
        $('#package-toogle').on('change', function () {
            $('#divParticipants').toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 400, function () {
            });

            $('#divPackage').toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 400, function () {
            });
          $('#add-new').toggle();
        })
    });
```

Comment: It's not a perfect solution, but it's based on your's - so it's easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you. How can I combine fade in and slide ?

Comment: I would consider using CSS for that (and skipping jQuery for more vanlilla JS. See documentation for querySelector and classList). Good luck!